# Artifact id resolved wrong

Tags: gradle, build.gradle, gradle-plugin, gradlew, spring-boot-gradle-plugin

I am new to gradle and I am facing a weird problem while I’m trying to add a plugin in gradle. I know that we have to specify an if and version in plugin body for a gradle build, but I tried to add a plugin with some id and version.  My question is..how does a gradle build know which artifact id to choose if there are multiple artifacts under same group id? I know that this might be a lame question...but I’m pretty new to gradle and I’d like to know your input.

Comment: Please add either an example build or more details about your question.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to apply the `spring-boot-plugin`?

If so, does the project you're trying to apply the plugin to have a buildscript block like this:

```
buildscript {
  repositories {
    maven {
      url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
    }
  }
  dependencies {
    classpath "org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:2.0.4.RELEASE"
  }
}

apply plugin: "org.springframework.boot"
```

or a plugin closure:

```
plugins {
  id "org.springframework.boot" version "2.0.4.RELEASE"
}
```

With a buildscript block, Gradle knows where to find the plugin because I've specified a repository for it to go look for it. After resolving the dependency path it finds and downloads the plugin, then puts it on the classpath for use in `build.gradle` files. It then only needs to get applied, i.e. `apply plugin: ...`.

With the plugins closure, things are a bit trickier. Plugins are published under a unique id, which is looked up and gradle resolves the specified version. I'm not too terribly knowledgeable about how this is done, but here, [new plugin mechanism](https://plugins.gradle.org/plugin/org.springframework.boot#new-plugin-mechanism-info-body) , describes some differences between `buildscript {} apply plugin: ...` and `plugins {}`.

Comment: What you’re saying is that any one of above two should be sufficient. I think I’ve added both in my code. I’ll retest by having only one in the code.

Comment: Correct, either will suffice. See [Applying plugins with the plugins DSL](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/plugins.html#sec:plugins_block) for more information about how the `plugins {}` works

Comment: Thanks a lot. The above solution resolved the issue I’m facing.